# Shell wait command not waiting if similar process already running

Tags: bash, shell, wait, background-process, linux-mint

I'm new to Linux and shell scripting in general so in order to better understand how I can make multiple processes run in the background I've been running some tests. I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox &
firefox &
firefox &
wait
echo "done"
```

I ran it without at first having Firefox open and it did what I expected: It opened three Firefox windows and only printed "done" when I closed them all.

Later, however, I tried to execute the script after I already had a Firefox window running and this happened: It did open three new windows but it printed out "done" right away, without waiting for me to close any of them.

I had expected it to either behave as it had at first or to maybe wait for me to close all four browser windows (the three it started + the one I had started separately).

To make it even more confusing, this doesn't seem to happen with every program. It happened with LibreOfficeCalc and xed but not with gnome-calculator. It also doesn't seem to care that different programs are already running in the background.

What explains this behavior?

How can I write a script that starts multiple processes in background without having to worry about the interference of other processes that may already be running?

In case it's relevant: I'm using Linux Mint 18.3.

Comment: This is behavior specific to `firefox`, not general to bash. When you start a new instance, it connects via socket to any existing copy that's running and tells that old copy to start a new window, and then exits immediately.

Comment: I'd suggest you either edit your examples to work with something like `sleep` if you want to ask a generalized question, or edit the question to ask (in the title, tagging, &c) *explicitly* about firefox.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Why doesn't it behave the same way in the 1st scenario? That is, why doesn't the instance started by my 2nd "firefox &" just recognize the 1st one as an old copy, tell it to start a new window and exit immediately as well? Why do I have to close all three windows for the waiting to end? As for your second comment: I want to keep the question general, firefox is just one of the processes I mention in the question. Can you elaborate on your point about sleep? I don't want to wait a fixed amount of time, I want to wait until the processes are finished, so I need "wait", right?

Comment: It **does** behave the same way in the 1st scenario. The first instance owns all three windows, and only exits when all three of them are closed.

Comment: My point about sleep is that if you had a question that wasn't specific to firefox but was truly about the behavior of bash, you could use something like `sleep 1 & sleep 2 & sleep 3 & wait` to ask about it. The fact that you can't reproduce the problem when you use `sleep` instead of `firefox` is... well... kinda' my point.

Comment: Thanks! Now it makes sense! I'm going to assume programs that open multible "tabs" like LIbreOffice and xed behave the same way. As for using sleep , I see what you mean now. I misunderstood it as you saying I needed to use sleep instead of wait.